# Property of Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\mu$ a Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $C$ a bounded and measurable set and $F_i$ a countable family of closed ball. I also have that $\frac{\mu(C)}{\eta(n)}\le \mu (C \cap \bigcup \{ \bar{B} \colon \bar{B} \in F_i \})$
I'm not able to prove the following:

As $\mu(C)<\infty$, we can select a finite subfamily $F_i′\subset F_i$ with the property that 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mu(C)}{2\eta(n)}\le \mu (C \cap \bigcup \{ \bar{B} \colon \bar{B} \in F_i' \})
\end{equation}

Comment: What is $\eta(n)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael is a costant that depend on n, the dimension of the space. This is a part of the proof of Vitali property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is simply that if $F_i = \{\overline{B}_1, \overline{B}_2, \ldots\}$, by 
countable additivity $$\mu(C \cap \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \overline{B}_i) = \lim_{N\to \infty} \mu(C \cap \bigcup_{i=1}^N \overline{B}_i)$$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand...how, what you have wrote, answer to the question? thank you.

Comment: If $a < \lim_{N \to \infty} x_N$, then $x_N > a$ for sufficiently large $N$.